# Kernel Panic While Installing on older hardware

Tags: support

I keep getting a kernel panic after trying Ubuntu 64, Kubuntu 64 and 32, Xubuntu 64 and I even tried Manjaro. They are HP Compaq Elite, 3GHZ Intel Core Duo, 2GB Ram that were donated. The harddrives were apparently wiped. I tried using different thumbdrives and two of the 14 donated computer get the same errors.

[image: Kernel Panic Image]

Comment: You should run a RAM test to ensure the memory isn't broken.

Comment: I wonder if booting the live installer with ACPI off would make any difference.

Comment: I did use the Manjaro boot menu to run a ram test on the first machine.  I did not test on the second machine and I brought a third one home for the weekend to play with and have not done anything to that yet.  When I get home today I will try messing with ACPI settings and do some more testing on this one.

Comment: I tried that and it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update the BIOS.  Problem solved!